# Axios for Vue without install

Tags: vue.js, axios

I want to use only maven in my project, but I want to make small single page application with 3 buttons and 1 info box. Can I include axios like vue.js? I downloaded Vue.js file and writed path in `<scrypt>` in Index.html. I dont want to use npm, yarn, webpack or somethingg else. Maybe I can use something else, not Axios?

Comment: Add axios js file under <script> tag in your webpage

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cdn url and link it from your application: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js"></script>`

Of course you can add more options to the script tag

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers come with an API called `fetch`. If you use fetch, you do not need to use any external request libraries like `axios` or `request-promise`.

Here is the documentation for `fetch`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API